# 1ST TRIGGER delete leads

Tags: delete

I have never written a trigger before and dont know code.  I would like to create a trigger that deletes any leads that are sent to our junk leads que,  which is basically any lead that contains http or @  as part of the name.

Can anyone help this novice?  Also any suggestions on how to start learning apex?

Comment: Learning Apex Code is easy, even easier if you know a related language. I'd suggest learning Java first, using some tutorials or something like "Java in 24 Hours" by "Sams Teach Yourself" (I don't specifically endorse it, but I don't know many other books that are as simple to pick up). There's a nice tutorial called [Apex Quick Start](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs.htm) that would quickly get you going (hence the name).

Answer (score 2):

You won't know if the lead is in the queue until after it's been assigned by the assignment rule. Therefore, you need to use a future method. This means you need a class and a trigger, like this:

## Class

```
public class LeadUtils {
    @future public static void deleteJunkLeads(Id[] leadIds) {
        Id junkQueueId = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE DeveloperName = 'JunkLeadQueue' AND Type = 'Queue'].Id;
        delete [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :leadIds AND OwnerId = :junkQueueId];
    }
}
```

## Trigger

```
trigger queueDeleteJunkLeads on Lead (after insert) {
    LeadUtils.deleteJunkLeads(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```